# What does "dollar less than" mean in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Here's my sample makefile content:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
...
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

What does the `$<` mean here?

Comment: I really cannot understand why people are asking questions *before* reading any documentation. IMHO, it is slower to ask than to seek in the doc

Answer (score 3):

**Read the documentation** of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make). It is explained in the [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) section.

> `$<`
>
> The name of the first prerequisite. If the target got its recipe from an implicit rule, this will be the first prerequisite added by the implicit rule

Comment: Please consider marking as duplicate instead of answering when it's clear that the question has been asked and answered before.  Thanks.